# Wrong output in python, c# version works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# your code goes here

def lagrange(x0, xlist,ylist):
    wynik =float(0)
    if (len(xlist)!=len(ylist)):
        raise BufferError("Rozmiary list wartosci x i y musza byc takie same!")
    for i in range(len(xlist)):
        licznik=float(1)
        mianownik = float(1)
        for j in range(len(xlist)):
            if (i!=j):
                licznik=licznik*(x0-xlist[j])
                mianownik=mianownik*(xlist[i]-xlist[j])
        wynik=wynik+((licznik/mianownik)*ylist[i])
    return wynik


x=[2.0,4.0,5.0,6.0 ]
y=[0.57672, -0.06604, -0.32757, -0.27668]
print ("Lagrange polynomial for point 5.5 is %d" % lagrange(5.5, x, y))
```

Why do I get answer 0 after I run it? When rewritten to c# and run with the same data it outputs answer -0.3539. Seems to me like casting / rounding error but I'm struggling to find it without debugger.

I am completely new to python, I'm using basic IdleX on windows to code it.

Comment: minusone for the title...

Comment: is it Python 3 or 2 ?

Comment: Python 3.5, and I  fixed the title, when I started writing the question division by zero was my issue and I forgot to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not your function, it’s the printing.

The formatter `%d` is a *signed **integer** decimal*. So if you have `-0.354` as a result, it gets rounded to `0`.

Instead, print using `%f`:

```
>>> print ("Lagrange polynomial for point 5.5 is %f" % lagrange(5.5, x, y))
Lagrange polynomial for point 5.5 is -0.353952
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it. It's so obvious now I'm laughing at myself.

Comment: @Luntri You’re welcome :) Please remember to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) that solved the question. Not only here but also on your older questions too. That way, the question gets marked as resolved.